# How to wait for a complete page load, after a link was clicked in puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Let's say i use the page.click() function, to simulate a click on a link:

```
await page.click('.some_link')
```

In the new page rendered by the browser(full page load, not SPA), i want to use page.click() again, on some element. Problem is, that even though the button is being "clicked"(i see the element focused), **the attached JS listener doesn't fire**, which make me suspect that the click() function fires **before the new page was completely loaded.**

If i create a delay with setTimeOut, everything works.

To make things short: how do i make sure that a new page was fully loaded, after a navigation was triggered? I tried playing around with page.waitForNavigation(), always getting a timeout error(from the docs, it's not even clear to me, when this function needs to be used).